# How (or can) I backup a Google Artifact Registry instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I'm looking at moving to using Artifact Registry as a replacement for Artifactory and I wondering how, or if, I would backup the stored files to guard against a server failure?

Maybe that's not a thing I need to worry about with GCP?

Comment: I would say it is a thing you should worry about also in GCP. Multi-region is aimed for high availability, which is a different concept form "backup". With multi-region, things like deletion of an image, will be replicated.
I'm also looking for a way to backup the information, but it does not look like a service being provided by GCP, rather a thing to "cook ourselves".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artifact Registry is a managed Service. you don't have access to the underlying Infrastructure powering the service so you have to worry about backup.

You can read more about this here https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/repositories/repo-locations